# server side database handler script

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

We are pushing data from Linux device via Python to a RESTful API at cosm.com.  We would now like to implement the data handling and storage of this to our own server.  In particular, the HTTP PUT method is used to push to the site's API.

I am an R&D of 1 and am under the gun.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: may I ask, is it via a Python or rather Twisted Python?

Comment: What do you mean by _"hopefully"_? By the way it seems like your question would have a better fit on the [Cosm Community Forum](http://community.cosm.com/)